# Jabber server doesn't reply to Client Final Message

Tags: c#, xmpp

I'm working on my own Jabber client (mostly to learn both XMPP and C#) and currently I'm trying to connect to server using SCARAM-SHA-1 over TLS. TLS negotiation goes fine as well as First Client/Server messages exchange, I get Server Challenge and generating Client Final Message with following code:

```
//Following block generates Client Final Message
//---STEP 1. Creating Salted Password---
byte[] SaltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Salt);
byte[] SaltedPasswordBytes = GetSaltedPassword(UserPassword, Convert.FromBase64String(Salt), Iterations);

//---STEP 2. Creating Client Key---
byte[] ClientKeyBytes = GetHash("Client Key", SaltedPasswordBytes);
string ClientKey = BitConverter.ToString(ClientKeyBytes);

//---STEP 3. Creating Stored Key---
SHA1 StoredKeySHA = SHA1.Create();
byte[] StoredKeyBytes = StoredKeySHA.ComputeHash(ClientKeyBytes);
string StoredKey = BitConverter.ToString(StoredKeyBytes);
//---STEP 4. Creating Auth Message---
string AuthMessage = "n=test_guy,r=" + ClientNonce + "," + ServerChallenge + "," + "c=" + StringToBase64("n,,") + ",r=" + ClientAndServerNonces; //concern: AuthMessage might start with "n=<username>" or "n,,n=<username>" - which one is right?
LogRTB.Text += "AuthMessage is:\n" + AuthMessage + "\n";

//---STEP 5. Creating Client Signature---                    
byte[] ClientSignatureBytes = GetHash(AuthMessage, StoredKeyBytes);
string ClientSignature = BitConverter.ToString(ClientSignatureBytes);

//---STEP 6. Creating Client Proof---
LogRTB.Text += "---STEP 6. Calculating Client Proof---\n" + "Client Key is: " + ClientKey + "\nClientSignature is: " + ClientSignature;
byte[] ClientProofBytes = new byte[ClientKeyBytes.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < ClientKeyBytes.Length; ++i)
{
    ClientProofBytes[i] = (byte)(ClientKeyBytes[i] ^ ClientSignatureBytes[i]);
}
LogRTB.Text += "\nClient Proof (string) is: " + ClientProof + "\n";

//---STEP 7. Creating Server Key---                    
byte[] ServerKeyBytes = GetHash("Server Key", SaltedPasswordBytes);
string ServerKey = BitConverter.ToString(ServerKeyBytes);
LogRTB.Text += "Server Key is: " + ServerKey + "\n";

//---STEP 8. Creating Server Signature---                    
byte[] ServerSignatureBytes = GetHash(AuthMessage, ServerKeyBytes);
string ServerSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(ServerSignatureBytes);
//DONE!
ClientProof = StringToBase64(ClientProof);
string ClientResponse = "c=biws,r=" + ClientAndServerNonces +",p=" + ClientProof; //putting together Client Response (most important part of Client Final Message)
//ClientResponse.Replace("==",""); //NO! just no!
LogRTB.Text += "Client response is:\n" + ClientResponse + "\n"; //DEBUG!
string ClientResponseBase64 = StringToBase64(ClientResponse);                    
if (IsBase64String(ClientResponseBase64))
{
    string ClientFinalMessage = "<response xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">" + ClientResponseBase64 + "</response>";
    LogRTB.Text += "--> Client response (Client Final Message) is:\n" + ClientFinalMessage + "\n";
    LogRTB.Text += "--> SENDING NOW!\n";
    ServerReply = SendXMPPQueryOverTLS(ServerSocket, SecureConnection, ClientFinalMessage); //Sending Client Final Message                        
    LogRTB.Text += ServerReply;
}
```

Problem is - I don't get ANY reply from the server, when according to [RFC6120 (XMPP Core)](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#examples-s2s-sasl) server is supposed to reply with *failure* or *success* message. Also, if I deliberately send wrong message (for instance omitting Client Proof) it does reply with *bad-protocol* message. Server is ejabberd with default settings.

I spent couple of days trying to figure out what's wrong and now getting a bit desperate. I hope someone here will be able to help me.

(If needed I can also provide logs that my app generates during connection process)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested [agsXMPP](http://www.ag-software.net/agsxmpp-sdk/download/) SCRAM implementation and it works good with ejabberd. Try to compare with your code - https://github.com/meebey/agsxmpp/blob/master/agsxmpp/Sasl/Scram/ScramSha1Mechanism.cs